# RecyclerView is not displaying Programmatically CardView

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to create a `cardView` with `recyclerView` with creating the `CardView` programmatically, here is my code, if it is not possible please let me know to use `XML`

`onCreate` of the main class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson_layout, container, false);

    ExampleRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ExampleRecyclerView);
    List<ViewExample> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.i("dddddd", String.valueOf(exampleList)); 
    //alos the list just show [] in the Logs

    adapter = new ExampleAdapter(this, exampleList);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
    ExampleRecyclerView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    ExampleRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    ExampleRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

the `ViewExample` class

```
public class ViewExample {
    private String StepHeader, Code, Explanation;

    public ViewExample(String stepHeader, String code, String explanation) {
        StepHeader = stepHeader;
        Code = code;
        Explanation = explanation;
    }

    Getters & Setters are here...
}
```

And the `Adapter`

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleHolder> {

    CardView ExampleCV;
    List<ViewExample> exampleList;
    ViewLesson viewLesson;


    public ExampleAdapter(ViewLesson viewLesson, List<ViewExample> exampleList) {
        this.viewLesson = viewLesson;
        this.exampleList = exampleList;
    }


    public class ExampleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {  // here is where you define what text have value
        LinearLayout parentL;
        public ExampleHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            parentL = new LinearLayout(parentL.getContext());
            ExampleCV = new CardView(ExampleCV.getContext());
            ExampleCV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            parentL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            parentL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ExampleCV.addView(parentL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ExampleHolder(ExampleCV);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ExampleHolder holder, int position) {
        TextView tv = null;
        final TextView finalTv = tv;
        RootRef.child("Development").child("Level 2").child("Intent").child("Putextra").child("Examples")
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.i("isa 5air", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
                finalTv.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
                holder.parentL.addView(finalTv);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
    }
```

**Edit**
NB : I have noticed that the code doesn't enter `onBindViewHolder` as I put test Log in it it doesn't print out

Answer (score 0):

you can use in your `lesson_layout` with `cardview` as given below `cardview` can only one child you can use another container layout such `linear` or relative as you need

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

              ............some other views.....

        </LinearLayout>

 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: but i want to create a recycler view to add more that one with good prefomance

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it seems that you are passing empty list to `RecyclerView Adapter`

```
 List<ViewExample> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
 Log.i("dddddd", String.valueOf(exampleList)); 
 //alos the list just show [] in the Logs
 adapter = new ExampleAdapter(this, exampleList);
```

Suggested changes:

1.You can Add some elements in it before passing to the adapter or add element in list and then call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

2.In your `ExampleAdapter` change `getItemCount()` method with bellow

```
 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
     return exampleList.size();
 }
```

**Edit:**

3.Change your `onCreateViewHolder()`

```
 @Override
 public ExampleHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ExampleCV = new CardView(ExampleCV.getContext());
        ExampleCV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    return new ExampleHolder(ExampleCV);
}
```

4.Constructor of `ExampleHolder` with:

```
 public ExampleHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        parentL = new LinearLayout(parentL.getContext());

        parentL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        parentL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        itemView.addView(parentL);
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, but it doesn't work show the data also will I have tried to put notifyDataSetChanged in onCreate before the adapter and after getting the data from firebase not working, is it the wrong place? or I'm calling the CardView the wrong way ?

Comment: have you changed your 'getItemCount()' method

Comment: yes, also I noticed that it doesn't enter onBindViewHolder method